# Translate mixed languages to single language

Tags: google-translate, translate, mixed

I would like to allow users to view a list of mixed-language comments (ie ten in English and four in Spanish) in their preferred language. I am only able to get Google Translate to translate the list to Spanish. How do I use Google Translate to translate the Spanish inputs to English? When I select "English" it just shows me the original mixed inputs.

Comment: Can you show your code for translating?

Comment: Thanks Rocco. I wanted to simplify my code prior to posting it and it ended up working.

Answer (score 0):

My mistake. I reverted to W3C example code and it worked as I had intended.